# Express with mongodb find one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im new to nodejs , express and mongodb.
I got stuck at the findOne function using ObjectId of mongodb

With the code below, I got the error : "Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"
Im using lastest version of everything (because Im new to them)

[image]

My code in view:

```
<% for(var i = 0 ; i < posts.length; i++ ) {  %>
                  <% post = posts[i] %>
                  <article class="post">
                    <div class="post-preview col-xs-10 no-gutter">
                      <h2>
                        <a href="/posts/<%=i%>">
                          <%= post.title %>
                        </a>
                      </h2>
                      <p><%= post.description %></p>
                      <p class="meta">
                        <a href="author.html"><%= post.author.name %></a> in
                        <a href="category.html"><%= post.category.name %></a> <i class="link-spacer"></i> <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> <%= post.created_at %>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-xs-2 no-gutter">
                      <img src="<%= post.author.image %>" class="user-icon" alt="user-image">
                    </div>
                  </article>
                <% } %>
```

Please tell me what's wrong with my code .
p/s : the req.params.id is valid and logable.

Comment: can you print `id` ?

Comment: @Jérôme yes, I can, as I said it logable .
route: /posts/1 -> id is logged as 1

Comment: The problem is that 1 is not a valid ObjectId

Comment: @JohnnyHK how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default mongo IDs don't increment from 1. They will look like `"_id" : ObjectId("5908f94c06515dfa8522459c")` in the database. Your problem is your href is navigating by index, not the id itself. You need to change:

```
<a href="/posts/<%=i%>">
  <%= post.title %>
</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>">
  <%= post.title %>
</a>
```

this will make your link `/posts/5908f94c06515dfa8522459c` instead of `/posts/1`

Comment: Thank you. But if I want to have my URL like /posts/1 then how can I do it ?

Comment: You'll need to add a new field to your documents: `myOtherId`, and then query by that field. You'll need to have an incrementing function that runs before you insert new documents. For persistence, you'll have to create another collection to keep the current value of your increment. I'd look around for "mongo autoincrement". I'm sure others have done it before.

Comment: hmm,that's new to me, Im from rails and have no idea about all of this, I 'll do more research. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because the id is a string of not 12 bytes (nor 24 hex characters). When the URL comes in to your express web server, it's a string. When express matches a part of it and stores it, there's no rule that `:id` couldn't be `myCoolId`, which isn't a number.

So everything in `req.params` is a string. I would add some checking to make sure it's a number, cast it, and **then** give it to `ObjectId`.

EDIT: If you want to work with it as strings, then try some of the following:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

// When making a brand new record, just use a new object id.
let record = new ObjectID();
console.log(record);

// When giving the ID to the client as a string, make it a hex string.
let hexString = record.toHexString();
console.log(hexString);

// You can validate that it's a valid object id in your route when they post it back.
let valid = ObjectID.isValid(hexString);
console.log(valid);

// Then you can turn it back into an object id.
let fromHex = ObjectID.createFromHexString(hexString);
console.log(fromHex);
```

Comment: So when I loop the link to post single page, what should I put in the URL ?

Comment: `ObjectId` has a number of methods on it that can help you. [toHexString](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/ObjectID.html#toHexString) and [createFromHexString](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/ObjectID.html#.createFromHexString) will allow you to convert it in and out of a string that you can send to the client to link against. When a string comes in, you can use [ObjectId.isValid](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/ObjectID.html#.isValid) to check if it's good before using.

Comment: @DuongBach To make a new object id all you have to do is `new ObjectID()` with no params. It'll make a new one. Then you can start calling those methods on it.

Comment: @DuongBach I added an edit with some examples of things you can do with `ObjectID` in case that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your patience and kindness